# Show button only when it has data

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

How can I show a button only if it contains the database link?

I have a list of products, and some of them will have a link to more blog information. I would like to show this button only when the link exists in the database.

```ts
buttonlink: null;

constructor(){
   this.buttonlink = this.produto.link_blog;
}
```

```html
<button ion-button-end *ngIf="buttonlink" 
(click)="openWithSystemBrowser(produto.link_blog)" class="agendacultural- 
 quero">VEJA NO BLOG!</button>
```

Comment: can you show the code where you get the data of this `this.produto.link_blog;`

Comment: cab you add `{{buttonlink}}` before your `button` in your html, to make sure it's null

Answer (score 0):

Try this idea

Make initial value is empty string

```
buttonlink = ''
```

And check for buttonLink length in button

```
<button ion-button-end *ngIf="buttonlink.length > 0"(click)="openWithSystemBrowser(produto.link_blog)" class="agendacultural- quero">VEJA NO BLOG!</button>
```

Comment: it does not return any buttons. if I put buttonlink = '1' it returns, I do not know how I should add the contents of the database to check

Comment: So the real problem is that you haven't populated `this.produto.link_blog`?